# Trigger on Notes object is not firing

Tags: triggers, salesforce

trigger LMDofNotes on Note (after insert, after update) {

```
Id  accountId;
Date LMDofNote;


for(Note att: Trigger.new){
    accountId = att.ParentId;
    LMDofNote= (Date)att.LastModifiedDate;

}
Account  acc = [Select Id,LMD_of_Notes__c from Account where Id=:accountId LIMIT 1];

acc.LMD_of_Notes__c = LMDofNote;
update acc;
system.debug('updated date'+LMDofNote);
```

}

Comment: Could you please add some question statement along with the code.

Comment: If your org is using Enhanced Notes, which it likely is, this trigger is on the wrong object.

Comment: @psyco :- Whenever a Note is created/updated, I would like to have Last modified date of Notes to be updated on custom Date field on Account object. Currently I have created above trigger but it is not firing whenever I create a new note on account record, can you please help?

Comment: @DavidReed, Yeah I am using enhanced Notes(where we are able to write rich text content), can you please let me know object API name for enhanced Notes, so that I can replace it with 'Note' in my code. Is it ContentNote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Orgs with Enhanced Notes active do not create `Note` records, which represents classic Notes.

Instead, they create [`ContentNote`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentnote.htm) records, which are part of a [much more complex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_erd_contentnote.htm#!) ERD. `ContentNote` doesn't have a `ParentId` field (its relationship to records is many-to-many), so your trigger would have to be on the [`ContentDocumentLink`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentdocumentlink.htm#topic-title) object.

`ContentNote` is basically a facade on the underlying `ContentDocument` and `ContentVersion` objects, but you can identify the note records by the `FileType` field:

> All notes have a file type of SNOTE.

Be aware that `ContentDocumentLink` is used for linking *all* Content records (not just notes) to sObjects, and that there are unique restrictions on querying it that are described in the documentation linked above.

Comment: trigger LMDofNotes on ContentDocumentLink (before insert, after update) {
    
   Id  accountId;
    DateTime LMDofNote;
    
    
    for(ContentDocumentLink att: Trigger.new){
       accountId = att.LinkedEntityId  ;
        LMDofNote= att.SystemModstamp ;
       
    }
    
    Account  acc = [Select Id,LMD_of_Notes__c from Account where Id=:accountId LIMIT 1];
    if(acc!=null){
        system.debug('im in Notes trigger');
        acc.LMD_of_Notes__c = LMDofNote;
        update acc;
    }
   
}

Comment: re wrote the trigger code on ContentDocumentLink object, and LinkedEntityId is giving my Id instead of Id (accountId) on which I am trying to create...how to get accountId(on which I am trying to create Note)?

Comment: @Sivananda2320 There will in often be more than one `ContentDocumentLink`. Content sharing is complex. You are the owner of the Note so it's shared to you.